# How to set all zeros in Timestamp instance in java?

Tags: java, initialization, timestamp

I needed to set all zeros in Timestamp instance.

Here is the code I tried

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class UI
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("0000-00-00 00:00:00.0");
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

It is showing output

```
0002-11-30 00:00:00.0
```

How to set the value of Timestamp so that output will show

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: @TAsk: Month 00 is january

Comment: Can you explain your question? All zeros in year means the year zero, meaning approximate time of birth of Christ.

Comment: Ok, Whay it is showing this 0002-11-30 00:00:00.0 and how can we set all zeros.

Comment: @Basil Bourque Yes, You are right. I want to set this type of value.

Comment: You want a date-time for two millennia ago? Time of day and exact dates have no meaning in ancient history. Usually people use other data types for such purposes.

Comment: At least the day 0 is invalid. Month 0 is ok since it is january, but I do not think that it is possible otherwise. Couldn't you just store the value as a float, and if it is a correct date ( != -1 or so ) you could then restore as timestamp?

Comment: this gives me an Exception **Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]**

Comment: @Basil Bourque This may have no meaning. But I have an instance of Timestamp and I have to initialize it with all zero if it is possible.

Comment: @Ankit Lamba No Exception on my machine.

Comment: @Pphoenix Yes. We may byt here I have an instance of Timestamp and I have to initialize it with all zeros if it is possible.

Comment: @Varun: Updated with an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to instantiate a `Timestamp` to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.
`valueOf` calls a constructor, which in the source code has the following javadocs (taken from [offical javadocs API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)):

```
Constructs a Timestamp object initialized with the given values.

Deprecated: instead use the constructor Timestamp(long millis)

Parameters:
year the year minus 1900
month 0 to 11
date 1 to 31
hour 0 to 23
minute 0 to 59
second 0 to 59
nano 0 to 999,999,999
```

The date parameter must be of value between 1-31.

Comment: If you check my answer below you will see that it is actually possible to have a Timestamp that has 0000-00-00 00:00:00 when toString is called.

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN While your answer is technically correct, I would really advice *against* using reflection to modify an instance in such a way. It will lead to unpredictable behaviour and bugs. If one absolutely must have a Timestamp with all zeros, I would suggest writing your own implementation that supports it, that way it is easier to maintain and less prone to error

Comment: I completely agree with you, I just wanted to show that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

`'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` can not be represented as `java.sql.Timestamp`

Try this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String[] s = {"0001-01-01 00:00:00.0", "0000-00-00 00:00:00"};
        for (String value : s) {
            Timestamp t = Timestamp.valueOf(value);
            System.out.println(t.toString() + ", " + t.getTime());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: this is what I'm trying to say [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648035/how-to-set-all-zeros-in-timestamp-instance-in-java?noredirect=1#comment38206667_24648035)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 0th month which has a 0th day (and no 0th year depending on your calendar).  If you want to change how the timestamp prints you can do this

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE) {
    public String toString() {
        return "0000-00-00 00:00:00.0";
    }
};
```

This will print the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on the [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) Documentation reveals that the Class - **Timestamp** only supports the following parameter values:

- **year** - the year minus 1900
- **month** - 0 to 11
- **date** - 1 to 31
- **hour** - 0 to 23
- **minute** - 0 to 59
- **second** - 0 to 59
- **nano** - 0 to 999,999,999

So, the answer to your question is that, you cannot set the value to:
    `0000-00-00 00:00:00.0`
However, you can set the hour, minute, second and nanosecond value to `00:00:00.0`.

Were you able to execute your code successfully?
Executing your code resulted in:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to do this via reflection. Internally the timestamp object has another date object which is not accessible outside.

```
public static void convertTimestampToZero(final Timestamp t) {
    // normalize the timestamp to generate internal date object
    t.toString();

    // reset the nano seconds
    resetInternalDateField(t, "fastTime");
    resetInternalDateField(t, "nanos");
    
    // get the internal date object
    Field cdateField = getDeclaredFieldInHierarchy(t.getClass(), "cdate");
    Object cdate = getIgnoreAccess(t, cdateField);
    
    // convert fields to zero
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "year");
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "month");
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "dayOfMonth");
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "dayOfWeek");

    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "hours");
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "minutes");
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "seconds");
    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "millis");

    resetInternalDateField(cdate, "fraction");
}

private static void resetInternalDateField(final Object o, final String fieldName) {
    Field field = getDeclaredFieldInHierarchy(o.getClass(), fieldName);
    setIgnoreAccess(o, field, 0);
}

public static Field getDeclaredFieldInHierarchy(final Class<?> cls, final String fieldName) {
    if (null == cls) {
        return null;
    }
    List<Field> fields = getDeclaredFieldsInHierarchy(cls);
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getName().equals(fieldName)) {
            return field;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just implement the getIgnoreAccess/setIgnoreAccess methods which just get/set the value of a field via reflection ignoring the access modifiers.

And here's a test:

```
@Test
void shouldGenerateAZeroTimestamp() {
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(4324629);

    convertTimestampToZero(t);

    assertThat(t.toString(), equalTo("0000-00-00 00:00:00.0"));
}
```